# spring boot mongodb repository : custom method not working when capital data in database why? but small case it work

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

```
@Repository
public interface Repository extends MongoRepository<Patient, String> {

//  Search Methods

    List<Patient> findByFirstname(String firstName);
    
    List<Patient> findByLastname(String lastName);
    
    List<Patient> findByEmail(String email);
    
    List<Patient> findByPincode(String pincode);
    
    List<Patient> findByContactnumber(String contactDetails);
    
    List<Patient> findByCity(String city);

}
```

I have created a custom find method, but this method not working when the FirstName is like -> Subham or SUBHAM but it works when the FirstName is subham. Can you please help to solve this problem?

the lowercase works every time but the uppercase does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know regarding MongoRepository, but we got the same problem, and the solution was:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.*;

Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("firstName").is(firstName);
Collation collation = Collation.of(Locale.ENGLISH).strength(Collation.ComparisonLevel.secondary());
Query query = new Query(criteria).collation(collation);
return mongoTemplate.findOne(query, Patient.class);
```